# Show that there's a bijective $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{f(n)}\ln\frac{f(n)+1}{f(n)}=\ln 2010$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I show that:

> There exists a bijective $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{f(n)}\ln\frac{f(n)+1}{f(n)}=\ln 2010$$

I have really no idea where to begin... Taylor series doesn't seem related. I thought about the alternating series test which approximates the sum but not sure how to use it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried taking the exponential of both sides?

Comment: Now that you mention it, it seems obvious. Taking the exponential gives $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{1}{f(n)})^{(-1)^{f(n)}}=2010$. I'll think about it a little, nothing pops to mind yet.

Comment: Not quite.  The sum turns into a product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose first you take $f(n)=2n$ then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{2n}\ln\frac{2n+1}{2n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(2n+1)-\ln(2n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2n+\delta_n} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2n+1} = \infty$$
where $0<\delta_n<1$ - this is Lagrange's theorem $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{(x)-y)} = f' (c)$ for some $c\in (x, y)$, and here $x=2n+1,\; y=2n,\; f(t)=\ln(t)$ so $f'(t)=\frac{1}{t}$.

The same works for $f(n)=2n+1$ but with $-\infty$. Now construct another function $f$ as follows : choose enough even numbers until the first time your partial sum is above $\ln 2100$, then choose enough odd numbers until the first time your partial sum is below $\ln 2100$. you can do this since the two sequences I described above converge to $\pm \infty$. you can continue like this to build a bijective map $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Since the $n-th$ term in the sum converges to zero, show that the sequence converges to $\ln 2100$.

Comment: @Promotheus: Very nice! Thank you for the argument.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I'm familiar with Lagrange's theorem, and there seem to be a few, which one did you mean? Also, the question explicitly states "there's no need to look for $f(n)$" ;) but I'll try to understand your argument nonetheless.

Comment: This is essentially a proof of the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), which the question is a special case of.

Comment: @daniel.jeckson: edited the part about Lagrange's theorem. also, this argument is basically the Riemann series theorem, so you might want to look at it also.

Comment: ofcourse, I completely forgot about Riemann rearrangement theorem! I can take $f(n)=n$ and show that $\sum (-1)^n \ln (1+\frac{1}{n})$ converges conditionally and then use the theorem.

Comment: @Prometheus: I think most people call your Lagrange's theorem the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).